# Is there a way to make almost all video files work on Ubuntu using a media player, or a codec installation pack?

Tags: sound, video, multimedia, codecs

I used to use Media Player Classic in Windows and it played everything!

I've installed VLC on my Ubuntu 12.04 system and while it plays 99% of the files I try to play on it, there are these video files from a Coursera torrent that I'm trying to play but the audio is cracking a LOT!

The same file, when played on VLC or Media Player Classic on Windows, plays with very minimal cracks in audio and is considerably better and also audible.

I was wondering if there's some all-in-one codec pack like K-lite pack (or media player classic) for windows that will take care of my problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can install `ubuntu-restricted-extras` from the Software center.  This installs all the non-free codecs for almost everything.

Comment: Answered first, hence marked.

Answer (score 4):

Open termina; (Ctrl + Alt + T) and run this command

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```